# Create an append by getting id

Tags: jquery, append, getattribute

So I'm trying to have it so that when i click this

```
<a class="tab" id="NAME">NAME</a>
```

in id=gamecontent it will create this

```
<div id="NAME" class="tabcontent">
<h3>NAME</h3>
<embed src="games/NAME.swf" align="middle" height="570px" width="100%"/>
</div>
```

and this is what i came up with

```
$('.tab').click(function() {
var x = $(this).getAttribute('id');
$('#gamecontent').append('<div id="' + x + '" class="tabcontent"><h3>' + x + '</h3><embed src="games/' + x + '.swf" align="middle" height="480px" display="block" width="100%"/></div>');
});
```

it seemed simple enough but something somewhere makes it just not work at all

Comment: `getAttribute` is a plain js .. `.attr()` is a jquery .. so you just need to change `.getAttribute('id')` to `attr('id')`  or `var x = this.id`

Comment: ahhh thank you! i knew it had to be something small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commentary says, you used a wrong method to get the `id` attribute. Corrected that error, I show an alternative to create elements with JQuery instead of using the full string definition:

```js
$('.tab').click(function()
{
    var x = $(this).attr('id');
    
    var div = $("<div>", {
        id: x,
        class: "tabcontent"
    });

    var h3 = $("<h3>").text(x);
    
    var embed = $("<embed>", {
        src: "games/" + x + ".swf",
        align: "middle",
        height: "480px",
        width: "100%",
        display: "block"
    });

    div.append([h3,embed]);
    $("#gamecontent").append(div);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="tab" id="NAME">NAME</a>
<hr>
<div id="gamecontent"></div>
```

You can check with the **inspector tool** the format of the appended content, after you made the click...